# Ubuntu 22.04 keeps reconnecting to AirPods when you connect to them with another device

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

Connecting AirPods to Ubuntu 22.04 worked perfectly fine without any extra tinkering.

However, when I try to connect to the same airpods with an iPhone while they are connected to Ubuntu, it works for a minute, but then Ubuntu takes over control again and the iPhone disconnects.

Is there any bluetooth config that controls whether Ubuntu tries to reconnect to disconnected devices?

Comment: If you disconnect them Ubuntu won't try to reconnect.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to disconnect it manually every time. It used to work properly on 20.04.

Comment: 20.04 uses Pulseaudio; 22.04 uses Pipewire. The latter has better support for Bluetooth audio devices and among other improvements it scans for devices much more aggressively.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by setting `ReconnectAttempts=0` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and restarting the bluetooth service.

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for this for ages!